# Getting elements in certain range of list

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list, for example `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. In addition, I have another list `list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j']`. Now I would like to do the following:

```
idx = (list > 3) & (list < 7)
list2 = list2[idx]
```

This should yield `['d','e','f']`. Of course, this is not possible with lists. How can this be done with lists?

Comment: Also check `enumerate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
l2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j']
result = [a for a, b in zip(l2, l1) if 3 < b < 7]
```

Output:

```
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

To get the reduced list as well:

```
result, reduced = map(list, zip(*[[a, b] for a, b in zip(l2, l1) if 3 < b < 7]))
```

Output:

```
['d', 'e', 'f'] #result
[4, 5, 6] #reduced
```

Comment: That works. How can I also get the reduced l1 list? That means [4,5,6].

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#Make sure all lists are numpy arrays.
import numpy as np
idx = np.where((list > 3) & (list < 7))
list2 = list2[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Option with list comprehension accessing elements by index:

```
res = [ list2[idx] for idx, e in enumerate(list1) if 7 > e > 3 ]
print(res) #=> ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

---

To get the elements from both the lists:

```
[ [list2[idx], e] for idx, e in enumerate(list1) if 7 > e > 3 ]
#=> [['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6]]
```

Then transpose:

```
res1, res2 = [ list(i) for i in zip(*[ [list2[idx], e] for idx, e in enumerate(list1) if 7 > e > 3 ]) ]
print (res1, res2 ) #=> ['d', 'e', 'f'] [4, 5, 6]
```